# Using winforms with a binding source, How do I know if the user has modified a record?

Tags: c#, winforms, entity-framework, bindingsource, bindingnavigator

I have a binding navigator with a bindingsource on a winforms form.
My datasource comes from an entity framework list.

I want to track the sate of each entity in my binding source, using a technique I learned from a [Julie Lerman Course at Pluralsight](http://pluralsight.com/training/courses/TableOfContents?courseName=efarchitecture&highlight=julie-lerman_efarchitecture-m2-boundedcontext!julie-lerman_efarchitecture-m3-archrepo!julie-lerman_efarchitecture-m4-testing!julie-lerman_efarchitecture-m1-overview#efarchitecture-m2-boundedcontext)

Adding and Editing are easy enough, I just filled in the Add and Delete button events

```
    private void bindingNavigatorAddNewItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ((IEntity)(this.personBindingSource.Current)).State = EntityState.Added;
    }

    private void bindingNavigatorDeleteItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ((IEntity)(this.personBindingSource.Current)).State = EntityState.Deleted;
    }
```

However there is no EditItemClick  event, How can I track if the entity has been modified?

Note I am binding to a disconnected list of a domain class Person

```
 List<Person> people = MyRepository.GetPeople();
 this.personBindingSource.DataSource =people;
 this.personBindingNavigator.BindingSource = this.personBindingSource;
```

I have an interface IENtity

```
public interface IEntity
{

    EntityState State { get; set; }
}



public enum EntityState
{
    Unchanged,
    Added,
    Modified,
    Deleted
}
```

and Person inherits from that
[Update]
looking at the bindingSource event properties, I see that CurrentItemChanged is raised when a property is modified. However it is also raised when the current item itself is changed.
Is there a way to work out which reason it was raised for?

Comment: How are you binding the data values to the controls in your binding navigator?  If you are binding the entity properties to the controls, then just changing the values via the UI should automatically set the `EntityState.Modified`.  The entity tracker should handle that for you if you bind properly.

Comment: Thanks @DavidTansey I updated the question to show that the entities are disconnected.

Answer (score 0):

As your entities are disconnected no change tracking by the context is available, therefore you need to track changes yourself.

If you change your repository method to create clones of the people you're retrieving we can reconnect the original entities at the point of save.

```
List<Person> originalPeople;
List<Person> modifiablePeople = MyRepository.GetPeople(out originalPeople);
```

You can read the section 
[Creating a cloned object containing current, original, or database values](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj592677) to find out how to create a clone of your original people objects.

MyRepository.SavePeople would take two arguments, originalPeople (the clones) and modifiablePeople (the modified people bound to the UI containing the changes). You would then reattach your originalPeople in an unmodified state and then apply the property changes from the modified person in at iterative fashion:

```
var entry = context.Entry(original Person); 
entry.CurrentValues.SetValues(modifiedPerson);
```

Read the section on:
[Setting current or original values from another object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj592677)

Comment: Thanks @user978139 , I am thinking there must be a way to flag the modification as it happens.... maybe something to do with INotifyChangeProperty

Comment: INotifyPropertyChanged is useful in binding circumstances to notify UI controls for updates in values. You could keep a string/boolean key value pair dictionary of the properties which have been modified for each entity which the repository has access to. In the repository you would iterate the dictionary and set the property as modified    context.Entry(blog).Property("Name").IsModified = true;

Comment: This doesn't answer my question. How do I know the bound object has been modified?

Answer (score 0):

```
private void bindingSource_ListChanged(object sender, ListChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.ListChangedType == ListChangedType.ItemChanged)
        {
            var entity = (IEntity)((BindingSource)sender).Current;
            if (entity.State == EntityState.Unchanged)
            {
                entity.State = EntityState.Modified;
            }
        }
    }
```